# Split python list based on repetition

Tags: python, list

How to split a list into different groups based on repetition.

Example input:

```
input_ = [1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]
```

Example output:

```
output_ = [[1,1,1],[2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

input_ = [1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]

output = [list(group) for val, group in groupby(input_)]

print(output)
#[[1, 1, 1], [2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If the input is like this:
input_ = [("a",[1]),("b",[1]),("a",[2]),("b",[2]),("a",[3]),("a",[4]),("b",[4]),("c",[4])]

and need to be group by the integer?

Comment: @ranaFire That is quite different than the original input and I suggest you to post a separate question. Anyway, nice answer.

Comment: @ranaFire It would depend on what your expected output would be.